# Return a subset of matching results in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, search

I have a MySQL DB containing elements and keywords.  If someone searches for an element by keyword they could get a huge number of hits.  Rather than returning ALL elements that match, I'd like to do the equivalent of returning the nth group of m elements.  This would allow me to display the first m matching elements, then get and display the next m matching elements, etc.

As a concrete example, imagine I have a DB of images and I search using the keyword "ball", and there are 500 total matches, I'd like to query the DB to return the first 50, then the second 50, etc.  Assuming the order of the elements is deterministic (using ORDER BY), I don't know how to sub-select a subset of those matching elements.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a LIMIT condition to your query, which allows you to specify a number of results, and a result offset.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword = 'ball' LIMIT 0, 50
```

Which would give you the first 50 results starting at result offset 0..

To get the next 50 you just change this to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE keyword = 'ball' LIMIT 50, 50
```

Which gives you 50 results starting at result offset 50.

Normally when you're coding pagination (Offering pages 1, 2, 3 of a result set), you pass the offset you want to begin at in the URL, in order to run the same query but get results starting from a different offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT keyword, otherfield from table
WHERE keyword LIKE '$keywordvar%'
ORDER BY whatever ASC
```

Then, use the [LIMIT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

To limit your query to the first 50 use:

```
LIMIT 50;
```

To limit your query to the second 50 use:

```
LIMIT 50, 50;
```

To limit your query to the third 50 use:

```
LIMIT 100, 50;
```

You can change the values to either larger or smaller sets.
Your final query would then look something like:

```
SELECT keyword, otherfield from table
WHERE keyword LIKE '$keywordvar%'
ORDER BY whatever ASC
LIMIT 50;
```

Or if your not using wildcard searching and looking for specific keyword values:

```
SELECT keyword, otherfield from table
WHERE keyword = 'ball'
ORDER BY whatever ASC
LIMIT 50;
```